# Customize Airflow / TFX Pipeline to upload Files in S3

Tags: amazon-s3, airflow, tfx, mwaa

I am currently trying to customize a tfx pipeline, which is being orchestrated by Airflow.

Basically I want to upload all generated files by the DAG to a S3 bucket storage after the run of the pipeline.
The issue is that every tfx pipeline component gets parsed into a individual DAG, because of this I can not access these via abc.downstream("xy")
By my understanding, see this documentation for how the pipeline gets build [dag-runner](https://github.com/tensorflow/tfx/blob/master/tfx/orchestration/airflow/airflow_dag_runner.py).

My code is based on the [tfx-taxi-example](https://github.com/tensorflow/tfx/blob/master/tfx/examples/chicago_taxi_pipeline/taxi_pipeline_simple.py).

Maybe I have not fully grasped the concepts of the TFX pipeline yet, so please make me aware if I am trying to solve this in a overly complex way.
I would greatly appreciate an alternative approach to what I am trying to accomplish ;)

Comment: Not sure what you want to fetch -> Perhaps the artifacts that you wrote in the S3 bucket? If yes, you can find them in your AIRFLOW_HOME which you define when you run this pipeline. An alternate would be to use ZenML, it has a simpler syntax and can fetch artifacts directly: https://github.com/zenml-io/zenml/tree/main/examples/airflow_local. P.S. Im the co-creator of ZenML (disclaimer), so let me know if you need help!

Comment: Thanks for reaching out! Actually I want to upload all the generated artifacts to a different s3 bucket. So after the normal tfx pipeline steps are run, I would like to move the data to a different bucket. 
I will definetly checkout your project.